# How do I remove JQuery UI autocomplete combobox text when user click on combobox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 5 jquery combobox on a single page and I want to remove text from combobox when user clicks on it. This should only remove text from selected combobox.

I use following code to convert dropdowns into jquery combobox

```
$(function() {
     $( "select" ).combobox();
});
```

Comment: try this  $("select").click(){
   $(this).val("");
};

Answer (score 0):

I think better could be

```
$("select").focus( function(){
    $(this).val("");
    } );
```

'cause it should work with [TAB] key too...

I'm right?

Comment: Well, the val() removes the value, if you want to remove text set text(""). Or am I missing someting?

Comment: I want to remove text, tried this $(this).text(""); but still text is there in combobox.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("select").focus( function(){
  $(this).html("");
});
```